# upgrading the cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm using cassandra 0.6.8 and I want to upgrade cassandra 0.6.8 to Cassandra 0.7, will it impact the data I currently have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NEWS.txt always covers upgrading:

### Upgrading

```
The Thrift API has changed in incompatible ways; see below, and refer
to http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions for a list of
higher-level clients that have been updated to support the 0.7 API.

The Cassandra inter-node protocol is incompatible with 0.6.x
releases (and with 0.7 beta1), meaning you will have to bring your
cluster down prior to upgrading: you cannot mix 0.6 and 0.7 nodes.

The hints schema was changed from 0.6 to 0.7. Cassandra automatically
snapshots and then truncates the hints column family as part of 
starting up 0.7 for the first time.

Keyspace and ColumnFamily definitions are stored in the system
keyspace, rather than the configuration file.

The process to upgrade is:
1) run "nodetool drain" on _each_ 0.6 node.  When drain finishes (log
   message "Node is drained" appears), stop the process.
2) Convert your storage-conf.xml to the new cassandra.yaml using 
   "bin/config-converter".  
3) Rename any of your keyspace or column family names that do not adhere
   to the '^\w+' regex convention.
4) Start up your cluster with the 0.7 version.
5) Initialize your Keyspace and ColumnFamily definitions using 
   "bin/schematool <host> <jmxport> import".  _You only need to do 
   this to one node_.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.if i upgrade will it affect my existing data.?and if it doesn't then how can i migrate my existing data from Cassandra 0.6.8 to Cassandra 0.7

Comment: No, the upgrade won't affect your existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will.
In my opinion you have to move manually your data from 0.6 to 0.7 by writing some code in java   or by another programming.